# Do invalid statements provide valid results

Tags: c++

I made this code and it should be invalid

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  a=3,014;    //invalid
  b=(3,014);  //invalid
  cout<<a<<endl<<b;
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
12
```

However both the invalid statements give valid results. But the result should be 3014. It is changed. Why does this happen?

Comment: You might also be interested in reading [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165)

Comment: You might be interested to know that since C++14, you can use single quotes as [digit separators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). So e.g. `a = 3'014;` would assign `3014` to `a`, but you'd have the readability improvement from a separator.

Comment: The first 'invalid statement' isn't invalid. The second one doesn't compile as shown, because of the period, so it can't produce anything. If the period is a typo and shouldn't be there, that statement isn't invalid either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing "invalid" about either of those.

```
a = 3,014;
```

This parenthesizes as

```
(a = 3) , 014;
```

So `a` gets assigned the value `3`, and then `014` (a number) gets evaluated and discarded. Hence, `a = 3`.

```
b = (3 , 014);
```

Here, we've explicitly put in parentheses. So the right-hand side is an application of the comma operator. The `3` gets evaluated then discarded. The `014` is an octal number, and `14` in base 8 is equal to `12` in base 10, so `b = 12`.